# Using div to expand with new information when "read more" is clicked and a close link to close it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website with a few div tags, i want it to expand with new information when the user clicks read more and a close link to close it.  I don't know how to use jQuery so JavaScript or/and css code would be helpful.  I have searched about the subject but nothing to my exact needs have come up.
Here is two of my div's as an example, i have edited this, but the expanded content does overlaps the rest of my content, any ideas?:

html:

```
<div class="servicesBox">

<p><b><u>Personal Breakthrough Sessions</u></b>
<br>
<i>“The secret of change is to focus all of your Energy, not on fighting the old, but on building the new.”</i>
<br>
    <b>Socrates  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;     &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;     &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;     &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;    

    <a aiotitle="click to expand" href="javascript:togglecomments('UniqueName')"
>    <u>Read more</u></a><br />
<div class="commenthidden" id="PBScontent"
>You know when you are ready to breakthrough what has been holding you back to be and do something more. A Breakthrough Session is one full day or 2 half days (within 2 days) where Louise supports you through identifying what has been limiting you and then by using the tools from Strategic Intervention, NLP, Time Line Therapy and Hypnosis training, helps you break down the barriers and create new options to start you on a journey to achieve what you want. Louise will work with you to devise a plan, and making you accountable by requesting that some immediate action is taken, as accountability is put in place. In addition will arrange follow – up sessions to determine how you are progressing, holding the client accountable for planned actions. A worthwhile investment to lasting change and success in all areas of your life.</div></b> </p>   
</div>

<div class="servicesBox">
    <p><b><u>Relationship and Family Coaching</u></b>
    <br>
    <i>“A real decision is measured by the fact that you've taken a new action. If there's no action, you've haven't truly decided"</i>
    <br>
    <b>Tony Robbins &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <u>Read more</u></b></p>    
    </div>
```

javascript:

```
//utility to set opacity
function setOpacity(e,v)
{
e.style.opacity = v;
e.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + (v*100) + ")";
}

function togglecomments (postid) {
var whichpost = document.getElementById(postid);
if (whichpost.className=="commentshown") { whichpost.className="commenthidden"; } else {      whichpost.className="commentshown"; }
}
```

css:

```
.demo {
  background: #969696;
  width: 690px;
  height:300px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  position:absolute;
}
#debug
{
    position:absolute;
    top:350px;
}

.commenthidden {display:none}
.commentshown {display:inline}
```

Comment: Have a look at [jquery slideToggle](https://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you said you don't know jQuery, but I made a solution using it anyway because it's actually very easy to implement.

HTML:

```
 <div class="servicesBox">

    <p><b><u>Personal Breakthrough Sessions</u></b>
    <br>
    <i>“The secret of change is to focus all of your Energy, not on fighting the old, but on building the new.”</i>
    <br>
        <b>Socrates  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;     &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;     &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;     &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;    

        <a id="clickme" href="#"><u>Read more</u></a><br />
<div id="PBScontent" class="commenthidden"
    You know when you are ready to breakthrough what has been holding you back to be and  do something more. A Breakthrough Session is one full day or 2 half days (within 2 days) where Louise supports you through identifying what has been limiting you and then by using the tools from Strategic Intervention, NLP, Time Line Therapy and Hypnosis training, helps you break down the barriers and create new options to start you on a journey to achieve what you want. Louise will work with you to devise a plan, and making you accountable by requesting that some immediate action is taken, as accountability is put in place. In addition will arrange follow – up sessions to determine how you are progressing, holding the client accountable for planned actions. A worthwhile investment to lasting change and success in all areas of your life.</div></b> </p>   
    </div>

    <div class="servicesBox">
        <p><b><u>Relationship and Family Coaching</u></b>
        <br>
        <i>“A real decision is measured by the fact that you've taken a new action. If there's no action, you've haven't truly decided"</i>
        <br>
        <b>Tony Robbins &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <u>Read more</u></b></p>    
        </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#clickme").click(function () {
        $("#PBScontent").slideToggle("slow")
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.demo {
    background: #969696;
    width: 690px;
    height:300px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 50px;
    position:absolute;
}
#debug {
    position:absolute;
    top:350px;
}
.commenthidden {
    display:none
}
.commentshown {
    display:inline
}
```

The jQuery calls the `.slideToggle` feature on the div when the link is clicked. Your content then slides up or down when the link is clicked. Just refer to one of the public instances of the jQuery library on your site, and you should be good to go.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hp27Y/) for an example.

If you wanted some kind of fade effect instead, you can switch `.slideToggle` for `.fadeToggle` in the jQuery code.

Comment: Thank you very much, this would be perfect but it doesnt seem to work, maybe because i dont know j query? I have put the j query into my javascript file, is that where it is supposed to go? @MattD

Comment: You have to include jQuery as well. You can do this by either downloading the version of jQuery you need (just about any version should do for this), adding it to a directory in your project, then adding a reference to it at the top of the HTML file for the page this is on. There are also instances of jQuery hosted by both Google and Microsoft that you can refer to as well. Here's Google's documentation on how to do that: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery. Just use the script line next to "snippet" in the jQuery section at the top of your HTML markup.

Comment: Further, you also need to add a reference to the jQuery script similar to how you would reference a JavaScript file.

Comment: Further reading on what you need to do in order to get jQuery working on your site: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp

Comment: I have tried copying and pasting the code into my HTML head but still doesnt work.  Is that what i was supposed to do? @MattD

Comment: No, you can't just copy the jQuery code from my example into your HTML. You also have to either download and include a copy of jQuery in your file structure for your site, and add a script reference to it in your header, or refer to a hosted instance of jQuery in your header. Check the w3schools.org link I added a few comments up. That should set you on the path to including and using jQuery correctly in your site.

Comment: Thanks, i have got it working! But there is one slight problem, when i click read more the information overlaps my other div's, is there a way to fix that? @MattD

Comment: Nothing comes to mind off the top of my head, I feel I'd have to be able to see the rest of your markup to really know. Could also be a browser issue. Try it in another browser to see if you get the same problem. Glad you got it working, though. If this solution is what you'll go with, please remember to accept it. :)

Comment: Checked different browsers and happens the same in every browser, would you like me to add the rest of my code? @MattD

Comment: You can, but that's likely better suited for another question. I'd also suggest just playing around with it to see what you can figure out yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, much appreciated.  I will try and play around with it then post a new question if i cant get it. Thanks again. @MattD

Comment: No worries, glad I could help and was able to show you that jQuery is actually fairly easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

To see how it is done using  JQuery, have a quick look at this [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_show)